# Digital Persona URU 4500 Web API (JavaScript SDK) giving ERR_SSL_VERSION CIPHER MISMATCH

Tags: c#, .net, localhost, biometrics, digital-persona-sdk

I am trying the web API sample application provided in SDK. SDK version is 3.2. I have installed SDK, Digital Persona Lite Client and driver. When I open web page then it does not show me the device and in the browser console, it shows:

> POST https://127.0.0.1:9001/connect net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

if I go to https://127.0.0.1:52181/get_connection I see:

```
{"endpoint":"https://127.0.0.1:9001/?web_sdk_id=556e6cc7-19f7-40db-82d4-59ef33433cfc&web_sdk_minport=9001&web_sdk_port=9001&web_sdk_secure=true&web_sdk_username=LvRZWhIxZtU&web_sdk_password=F3AD340EDFB7E403&web_sdk_salt=C9EEB4BDEFEA6BBFBD0CCAFF323E88D4AEBB12EC830C6224A785883E547942BE"}
```

In firefox I am seeing error if I try to access address with port 9001:

> An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:9001. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Comment: Could you please share your SDK with me?
I am also integrating Digital Persona U.are.U but I don't have the SDK. It will be a big help if you share this SDK with me.

Comment: @UbaidHussain Do not implement it on the web. You will not succeed it will only capture your finger but will not compare. The required engine does not work on the web. Instead, create the desktop app using WCF.  Also, using this device on web is security threat. Use apis and submit result there.

Comment: The compare feature is gonna run on server and in web we are just gonna capture the template

Comment: @UbaidHussain you can search my name on fb and send me a message.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head for 3 days I found the solution.

- Install Digtal Persona Client
- Install SDK
- Go to device manager -> In Biometric Devices right click on device -> Seelct update drive -> Select browse from my computer -> Select let me pick from my device -> Select URU 4500 Fingerprint Reader (Not WBF).
- Now important part repair Digital Persona Client and restart.